# Can I use identity in ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: rest, .net-core, jwt, identity

I have a REST API project that created in ASP.NET Core and clean architecture. Also, I have a React project that uses my REST API and they are in two projects. Can I use identity in my REST API project?

I think I can't use identity because my frontend project is in another project.

Comment: What do you mean by `identity`? Are you talking about the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) , ie. Microsoft Identity. You can certainly use it for your API and then use the `msal.js` script to authenticate and authorize users of your React front end with your asp.net core backend api. [ms-identity-ciam-javascript-tutorial-1-sign-in-react](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-ciam-javascript-tutorial/ms-identity-ciam-javascript-tutorial-1-sign-in-react/)

Comment: I mean exactly what you said.
Considering that the projects are separate from each other, is it possible to use Microsoft Authentication Library?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please read the linked article above for how to configure it and import the appropriate items for your front end.

Comment: This is a bit dated as it's backend is .net 5, but it goes through the configuration in Azure and some other relevant info: [configuring-azure-ad-authentication-for-a-reactaspnet-core-50-web-app-part-one](https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/10225/configuring-azure-ad-authentication-for-a-reactaspnet-core-50-web-app-part-one)

Comment: @RyanWilson Can I use JWT with Microsoft Authentication Library? If yes, How?

Comment: Yes, you can use JWT. When the front end authenticates with Azure it will return an authentication or id token based on your configuration, you just need to pass this in your request headers when calling your API. Your API should setup the JWT Authentication in your startup/program cs file of your API. You would then setup your Authorization policies there as well.

Comment: How I can a sample code of using JWT and Microsoft Authentication Library together in a .net core api project?

Comment: it walks through this in the second link I posted above. [configuring-azure-ad-authentication-for-a-reactaspnet-core-50-web-app-part-one](https://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/id/10225/configuring-azure-ad-authentication-for-a-reactaspnet-core-50-web-app-part-one), you can also find github example projects that outline the setup. Here's one more link that may help you: [how-to-setup-the-azure-ad-implicit-grant-flow-with-react-asp-net-core-and-rbac-roles](https://keithbabinec.com/2019/09/25/how-to-setup-the-azure-ad-implicit-grant-flow-with-react-asp-net-core-and-rbac-roles/)